# txt file format validation in java

Tags: java, validation, text, format

What is the best way to validate whether a .txt file is:

- In fact a .txt file and not another type of file with only the extension changed.
- The format of the .txt file matches the specified format (so it is able to be parsed correctly, contains all the relevant information, etc.)

This is all being done in Java, where a file will be retrieved and then needs to be checked to make sure it is what it is supposed to be.  So far I have only found JHOVE (and now JHOVE2) as tools for this task but have not found much in the way of documentation for implementing it within Java code as opposed to through the command line.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your definition of 'text file' with regards to character sets,  code pages, etc.?

Comment: Is the format a custom format or is it a known format like XML, JSON, or .properties?  If it's a custom format, would it be possible to switch to something more widely used and supported (like XML, etc)?

Comment: You mean a file that doenst have binary data? because you know, lots of things can be a text file. a xml is a text file, a html is a text file, even a graphics file, svg is a valid text file

Comment: Alongside the good questions above...how many lines of the file need to be read in order to establish that it's in the "specified format"?  Is the "specified format" dynamic or will it remain the same?

Comment: The format will be some type of custom format, not xml, etc.  As far as I know it should be static.

Comment: I don't have the exact 'specified format' as of yet, however I was hoping for something more general that would work if the format were to change.  For example, JHOVE, which I was exploring, is able to recognize many file formats.

Comment: @Greg - just wondering if the example I provided below was helpful or if you're going down a different direction altogether?  If you have any updates to this issue, you might want to post them as the SO community might be able to provide guidance on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it sounds like you're looking for a general sort of formatting option, could I recommend regular expressions to you?  You can do all sorts of different kinds of matching using regex.  I've written a simple example below [for all those regex experts out there, have mercy on me if I didn't use the perfect expression ;) ].  You could put the REGEX and MAX_LINES_TO_READ constants into a properties file and modify that to make it even more generalized.

You would basically test your ".txt" file for a maximum number of lines (however many lines are needed to establish the formatting is good - you could also use regular expressions for a header line or do multiple different regular expressions as needed to test the formatting) and if all those lines matched, the file would be flagged as "valid".

This is just an example for you to possibly run with.  You should implement proper exception handling other than just catching "Exception" for one.

For testing your regular expressions in Java, http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html works very nice.

Here's the "ValidateTxtFile" source...

```
import java.io.*;

public class ValidateTxtFile {

    private final int MAX_LINES_TO_READ = 5;

    private final String REGEX = ".{15}[ ]{5}.{15}[ ]{5}[-]\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}[ ]{9}\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}";

    public void testFile(String fileName) {

        int lineCounter = 1;

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            String line = br.readLine();

            while ((line != null) && (lineCounter <= MAX_LINES_TO_READ)) {

                // Validate the line is formatted correctly based on regular expressions                
                if (line.matches(REGEX)) {
                    System.out.println("Line " + lineCounter + " formatted correctly");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid format on line " + lineCounter + " (" + line + ")");
                }

                line = br.readLine();
                lineCounter++;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ValidateTxtFile vtf = new ValidateTxtFile();

        vtf.testFile("transactions.txt");
    }   
}
```

Here's what's in "transactions.txt"...

```
Electric            Electric Co.        -50.99         12/28/2011
Food                Food Store          -80.31         12/28/2011
Clothes             Clothing Store      -99.36         12/28/2011
Entertainment       Bowling             -30.4393       12/28/2011
Restaurant          Mcdonalds           -10.35         12/28/11
```

The output when I ran the app was...

```
Line 1 formatted correctly
Line 2 formatted correctly
Line 3 formatted correctly
Invalid format on line 4 (Entertainment       Bowling             -30.4393       12/28/2011)
Invalid format on line 5 (Restaurant          Mcdonalds           -10.35         12/28/11)
```

**EDIT 12/29/2011 about 10:00am**
Not sure if there is a performance concern on this or not, but just as an FYI I duplicated the entries in "transactions.txt" several times to build a text file with about 1.3 million rows in it and I was able to get through the whole file in about 7 seconds on my PC.  I changed the System.out's to just show a grand total count at the end of invalid (524,288) and valid (786,432) formatted entries.  "transactions.txt" was about 85mb in size.