# How to validate a uploaded file in java

Tags: java, regex, spring-mvc

I need to allow the user to upload only text files(.txt,.doc,.rtf etc). 
How can i validate the uploaded files contains only text data. 
I need to validate the data in the file not the file extension.

If the user uploads any Image or video files etc other than text files I need to display like
    "The format of the file you uploaded doesn't match the format required"

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659698/txt-file-format-validation-in-java

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576129/best-way-to-determine-mime-type-of-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Apache [Tika library](http://tika.apache.org/). It can find out type of a file by its content.