# Validate Format Tricky File Using Java

Tags: java, parsing, validation

I need to parse and validate a file whose format is a little bit tricky.

Basically the file comes in this format:

```
   \n -- just to make clear it may have empty lines
   CLIENT_ID
   A_NUMERIC_VALUE
   ONE_LINE_OF_SOME_RANDOM_COMMENT_ABOUT_THE_CLIENT
   ANOTHER_LINE_OF_SOME_RADOM_COMMENT_ABOUT_THE_CLIENT
   \n
   \n
   CLIENT_ID_2
   A_NUMERIC_VALUE_2
   ONE_LINE_OF_SOME_RANDOM_COMMENT_ABOUT_THE_CLIENT_2
   ANOTHER_LINE_OF_SOME_RADOM_COMMENT_ABOUT_THE_CLIENT_2
   OHH_THIS_ONE_HAS_THREE_LINES_OF_COMMENTS
```

The file will be big very seldom (10 mb is probably the biggest file I've ever seen - usually they have around 900kb-1mb).

So I have two problems:

1) How can I effectively validate the format of the file? Using regex + scanner? (I see this one as a very feasible option if I can transform each client entry into only one string - so I can apply the regex upon it).

2) I need to transform each of the entries in the file into Client objects. Should I validate the whole file before transforming it into Java objects? Or should I validate the file as I go on transforming its entry into Java objects? (Bear in mind that if any client entry is invalid, the processing halts immediately and an exception is thrown - hence any object that was created will be discarded).

I'm really keen to see your suggestions about question #1. Question #2 is more a curiosity of mine on how you would handle this situation. Ignore #2 if you will, but please answer #1 =)

Does anyone know any framework to help me on handling the file by the way?

Thanks.

**Update:**

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659698/txt-file-format-validation-in-java) and the problem is very similar to mine, but I'm not sure whether regex is the best way out to this problem. There might be quite a lot of "\n" throughout the file, varying number of comments for each client entry and an optional ID - hence the regex would have to be quite complex. That's why I mentioned transforming each entry into one row in the question #1 because this way would be much easier to create a regex to validate... nevertheless, this solution does not sound very elegant to my ears :(

Cheers.

Comment: for your 1st question, here's something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659698/txt-file-format-validation-in-java. see the answer's EDIT for performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd seen that question before and the problem is very similar to mine, but I'm not sure whether regex is the best way out to this problem. There might be quite a lot of "\n" throughout the file, varying number of comments for each client entry and an optional ID - hence the regex would have to be quite complex. That's why I mentioned transforming each entry into one row in the question #1 because this way would be much easier to create a regex to validate... nevertheless, this solution does not sound very elegant to my ears :( Keen to hear any other input. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to fail the batch if any part is found invalid, then validate the file first.

There are several advantages.  One is that validation and processing need not be synchronous.  If, for example, you process batches daily, but receive files throughout the day, you can validate them throughout the day and notify to correct problems before your scheduled processing.  Another is that validation of whether a file is well-formed is very fast.

A short, simple perl script would certainly do the job.  No need to transform the data, if I understand the pattern correctly, and it's all read-forward.

```
read past any newlines
read and validate a client id
read and validate a numeric value
read and validate one or more comments until a blank line is found
repeat the above four steps until EOF or invalid data detected
```

Comment: I should note that this validation can also be done in Java in much the same way... but if the processing and validation are independent of each other, then a scripted language may be more convenient.